# LBA starting address alignment from struct request

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm currently doing block drivers.  I've noticed during my tests that if
my platform is RHEL6.x/CentOS6.x my struct request's starting
LBA/sector is always aligned to 8 (e.g. 0, 8, 0x10, 0x100, 0x2508, etc.)
which is actually optimal for my designed driver and the firmware.  It seems the
struct requests are always aligned there.

On the other hand, if I test my driver on some older systems like Oracle 5.6,
the starting LBA for struct requests there seems not to be aligned to
8 - most cases the LBA is offseted (e.g. 0x2507, 300f, 0x95bd500f,
etc.)

My block queue settings and even looking from sysfs shows that my
logical block size and physical block size are 512 and 512,
respectively.  So I don't think it has something to do with 4kB
sectors.  What could be the setting that triggered such behaviour?  Is
there a request queue or gendisk setting that controls this that I may
not be aware of?  Or is this up to the FS layer?  Hopefully someone
can point it out.

Thanks!

Comment: *"So I don't think it has something to do with 4kB sectors"* -- Why not? Have you ever heard of "forward compatibility"?  Or what about  optimal performance for 512 B/sector emulation when the sector size is 4K bytes?  Read http://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/advanced-format-4k-sector-hard-drives-master-ti/

Comment: Well I assumed that because because my sysfs entries read both 512 bytes for both logical and physical blocks and no mention of 4kb.  Other entries like alignment_offset, minimum_io_size and optimal_io_size are 0, 512, 0, respectively.  Any way what you suggested could be worth investigating, how can I verify that forward compatibility is in effect in my newer systems?  So that I will implement that in my oldr systems like oel 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certainly because your partitions are aligned to 8-block boundaries on the newer system, but not on the older system (you can examine the partition table in detail with `sfdisk`).

Reads will be in units of the filesystem blocksize, which will be a multiple of the system pagesize (which is 4kB on the most common architectures).  So if your filesystem is offset from the start of the block device by a non-multiple of 8, all the reads will also be offset from a multiple of 8 by this amount.

Comment: I checked your suggestion, but with fdisk.  I use "fdisk /dev/<diskname>" mostly when partitioning, and this is what I did to both old (OEL5.6) and newer systems.  The resulting partition, when converted to sectors, both old and new systems mention that my partition 1 starts at sector/LBA 63.  Does that mean that either way, my partition is already unaligned wrt 8 blocks?

Comment: Yes.  This was common with older versions of fdisk, but newer versions should default to starting the first partition at LBA 2048.

Comment: Thanks.  I've verified that if I align the start of partition with 4kB c/o fdisk, I don't get non-4kB-aligned LBAs during file accesses.